# issue when using TortoiseSVN in win7

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.7.12. I am using win 7. I have checked out from a remote server, so I have a folder called project(there is green icon on it). Now I copy(right click->copy) project to the other folder called project2(there is also a green icon on the folder).

Question:

1. If I modify files in project2, then could I also update it to the remote server?
2. If I want project2 to be normal folder(without green icon), how could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can work with that working copy as usual (if you've copied the whole structure).
2. You should remove the `.svn` subfolder (it's hidden, so you'd need to enable showing hidden directories in Windows Explorer). Then it won't be a working copy anymore and you won't be able to update/commit from it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete .svn folder form second project folder...
Some time it may hidden ..
So check option  show hidden files...
then delete .svn file
then your project will be a normal folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that

And, There are 2 options for this, 1st is you do not check out the project but export it see the screen shot and 2nd option is the removal of .svn hidden sub folders.
[image]

Export option will not show the green sign on the folders.